# Converting a 2d String array to a 2d double array

Tags: java, arrays, string, double

I am making a project in which I need to put a certain precision(0.00 or 0.000) on values in a 2d array. The 2d array is a `String` and i want to convert it to `double`. But when I try, I get a `NullPointerException`, I don't know why.
Afterwards I want to again convert it to a `String` array.

print-method code:

```
public void printSheet() {
    int start = 'a';
    char letter = (char) start;
    //kolomnamen
    for (int i = 0; i < COLUMNS + 1; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            System.out.print("   ");
        } else if (WIDTH != 0) {
            String s = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH / 2; j++) {
                s += "-";
            }
            s += (char) (letter + i - 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH / 2; j++) {
                s += "-";
            }
            System.out.print(s + "\t");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < sheet.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(1 + i + "." + "    ");
        for (int j = 0; j < sheet[i].length; j++) {
             double[][] voorlopig = null;
            voorlopig[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(sheet[i][j]); //<-- problem
            double d = voorlopig[i][j];
           // String s = " " + sheet[i][j];

            System.out.println(voorlopig);
            double thaprez = (precision / precision) + (Math.pow(precision, 10)) - 1;
            d = Math.floor(d * thaprez + .5) / thaprez;
            String s = " " + voorlopig[i][j];

            if (sheet[i][j] == null) {
                System.out.print(s + "\t\t");
            } else if (sheet[i][j].length() < 10) {
                System.out.print(s + "\t");
            } else {
                System.out.print(s);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `private final int ROWS;
    private final int COLUMNS;
    private final int WIDTH;

    //datavelden
    private String[][] sheet;
    private String[][] values;
    private int precision;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to initialize your array  `double[][] voorlopig` maybe  like this:

```
  double[][] voorlopig = new double[sheet.length][sheet.length];
```

You get `NullPointerException` because the array `voorlopig` was `double[][] voorlopig = null;`

Answer (score 0):

```
double[][] voorlopig = null;
voorlopig[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(sheet[i][j]);
```

`voorlopig` is set to `null`, you'll get a `NullPointerException`.Initialize `voorlopig` before using it.